# Calling load on video tag before passing to canvas breaks it in React

Tags: reactjs, canvas, video

I have a React functional component in which I'm loading a video and am trying to pass it to a canvas object.

The relevant part of the code is

```
function onUploadVideoChange(event) {
event.persist();

const file = event.target.files[0];
const isAllowed = file.type === 'video/mp4';

if (!isAllowed) {
  alert('Only mp4 videos are allowed');
}
else {
  setUrlSource(URL.createObjectURL(file));
  videoRef.current.setAttribute('src', urlSource);
  videoRef.current.load();
  videoRef.current.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    const videoLength = videoRef.current.duration;
    const videoWidth = videoRef.current.videoWidth;
    const videoHeight = videoRef.current.videoHeight;

    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
    canvasRef.current.width = videoWidth;
    canvasRef.current.height = videoHeight;

    ctx.drawImage(videoRef.current, 0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);
  });
}
```

And down on my render is this part:

```
    <video ref={videoRef} controls>
      <source type="video/mp4" ref={sourceRef} src={urlSource} />
    </video>
    <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
```

As you can see, I'm using useRef hooks, but the video won't load in the canvas.

After some digging, I found out it's the `.load()` call that's for some reason breaking it. If I hard code the video URL on the `<source>` it works fine.

Here's a pen with it:

https://codepen.io/souljacker/pen/abvGmpy?editors=1011

I'm logging videoRef after calling load() and the video is there, with the proper src. So I'm stuck.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

*"I found out it's the .load() call that's for some reason breaking it."*

Not sure what's going on but... Just listening for `loadedmetadata` is not enough to draw an image from the video. The metadata is parsed but what if the pixels are not yet decoded and not available to snapshot? That will give you an unwanted result.

In the example below I modified your code to listen for a `play` event and then draw the video frame(s). Other ideas could be to load + pause, seek to a preferred time, then draw that frame as thumbnail.

PS: Use global vars where possible, don't trap them inside some function otherwise they only work (exist) inside that function. No other function will know what your `ctx` means if you define it only inside an event listener.

Your modified code for testing:

```
const { useRef, useState } = React;
var videoRef;
var canvasRef;
var sourceRef;
var ctx;

var videoWidth;
var videoHeight;


function Thumbnail() 
{ 
    videoRef = useRef();
    canvasRef = useRef();
    sourceRef = useRef();

    const [urlSource, setUrlSource] = useState(null);

    function onUploadVideoChange(event) 
    {
        event.persist();

        const file = event.target.files[0];
        const isAllowed = file.type === 'video/mp4';

        if (!isAllowed) { alert('Only mp4 videos are allowed'); }

        else 
        {
            videoRef.current.setAttribute('src', URL.createObjectURL(file));
            videoRef.current.load();
            console.log('src', videoRef.current.src);

            videoRef.current.addEventListener('play', handle_media_events );

            videoRef.current.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
            const videoLength = videoRef.current.duration;
            console.log("onUploadVideoChange -> videoLength", videoLength)
            videoWidth = videoRef.current.videoWidth;
            console.log("onUploadVideoChange -> videoWidth", videoWidth)
            videoHeight = videoRef.current.videoHeight;
            console.log("onUploadVideoChange -> videoHeight", videoHeight)

            videoRef.current.currentTime = Math.floor(videoLength / 2);
            console.log('video', videoRef.current);
            ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
            canvasRef.current.width = videoWidth;
            canvasRef.current.height = videoHeight;
          });
        }

    }

    return  ( 
                <div> 
                <input ref={videoRef} type="file" id="file" accept="video/mp4" onChange={onUploadVideoChange} />    
                <video ref={videoRef} controls> <source type="video/mp4" ref={sourceRef} /> </video>
                <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
                </div>
            ) 
}

function handle_media_events()
{
    if (event.type == "play") //# event can be "play", "pause", "seek", etc
    {
        //draw_video_Still(); //# for canvas with still image frame
        draw_video_Move(); //# for canvas with video motion
    }
}

function draw_video_Still()
{ 
    ctx.drawImage(videoRef.current, 0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);
}

function draw_video_Move()
{ 
    ctx.drawImage(videoRef.current, 0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);
    setTimeout( () => { draw_video_Move() }, 40 ); //# draw at every 40 millisecs   
}

ReactDOM.render(<Thumbnail/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```